# How to join steel pipe for decorative purposes

Tags: pipe, steel

I want to make a hanging bar made of steel pipe and connections for hanging some lamps. But I have no way to make the threads on steel and the only place I've found that does that wants to charge me a lot for making 4 end threads.

Can I weld or glue it somehow? I won't be subject to any strees or force and will hold at most a few grams from 5 lamps and sockets.

I think that I need to file the ends of the pipe so that it can fit inside the threaded connections, what is fastest way of doing that?

Comment: Could you use a smaller or larger pipe that just goes into or over the pipe you are using to make a coupler.    Then screw, pop rivet, or set screw it to hold?  Or would that get in the way?

Comment: That could indeed work just fine, I just have to check if the sizes match or if I will have to shim it somehow. I plan on using 3/4" pipe and fittings, but I think that the inner size of the fittings is larger than the inner size of the pipe.

Comment: You might as well just use 3/4" EMT then. But the title says, "for decorative purposes." Various lengths of threaded pipe can be bought.

Comment: What is EMT? Here (Brasil) the steel pipe is sold in bars and you must have the tools or pay a machinist to put the threads on for you

Comment: [Electrical Metallic Tubing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_conduit)

Answer (score 1):

**Use pipe shorts** (nipples), they're threaded on both ends and can be acquired in various foot lengths, and *everything* in between a 'close nipple' (~0") up to 18". But you should price check the cost of a threading verses a short, and which one would be less of a headache for you.

Or use EMT. For esthetics, use compression fittings and paint everything black.

**Do not file away** some of the OD and jamb a steel pipe into a fitting. You do not want it to fall on someone. For that same reason, **do not use adhesive**.

Although **it would work, if you knew how to weld** and owned a welder, I don't think you'd be asking this question.

I'm hip to decorative steel pipe, but only if it's threaded together. Using couplings that don't belong on steel pipe would scream "DiY project". And joining pipe together poorly would be poor form. If you're going to hang 3/4" steel pipe above my head, I expect to be able to do pull-ups off it. If you go with 3/4" EMT, then whatever. But if you do you'll lose the decorative aspect; EMT is simply cheap, easy, and functional. Where as with pipe, you can always still see some thread and tell it's robust - that's part of its charm.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility you might consider:

[image]

Kee clamps or equivalent for pipe diameter.

---

Another possibility:

[image]

Pipe threading tool kit.

Comment: I will try to find those kee clamps (or equivalent in Brazil), a pipe threading kit is too expensive for a single use job (that doesn't even require the pipes to sealed when connected).